# Travis error repository not Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, git-submodules

My folder structure is as below
    rserver-docker contains gitsubmodule of rserver

git submodule(rserver-docker) is as below:

```
[submodule "rserver"]   
path = rserver  
url = git@github.com:VInc/rserver.git
```

Travis looks as below

```
before_install:
  - echo $CI_USER_TOKEN
  - echo -e "\n\nmachine github.com\n login $CI_USER_TOKEN\n" >>~/.netrc
  - git submodule update --init --recursive
```

CI_USER_TOKEN is Personal access token updated in Travis-settings

I am getting error as below

```
 $ git clone --depth=50 --branch=dev git@github.com:VInc/rserver-docker.git VInc/rserver-docker
Cloning into 'VInc/rserver-docker'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.
$ cd VInc/rserver-docker
$ git checkout -qf d445f5afe71a6f3390345842644e600ee4bbb68b
7.47s$ git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule 'rserver' (git@github.com:VInc/rserver.git) registered for path 'rserver'
Cloning into '/home/travis/build/VInc/rserver-docker/rserver'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:VInc/rserver.git' into submodule path '/home/travis/build/VInc/rserver-docker/rserver' failed
Failed to clone 'rserver'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/home/travis/build/VInc/rserver-docker/rserver'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
```

Answer (score 4):

From Travis doc on the subject:

> #### [Git cannot clone my Submodules #](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#git-cannot-clone-my-submodules)
>
> If your project uses Git submodules, make sure you use public Git
>   URLs. For example, on GitHub, instead of
>
> ```
> git@github.com:someuser/somelibrary.git
> ```
>
> use
>
> ```
> https://github.com/someuser/somelibrary.git
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It was issue with Personal access token  as it didnot have permissions to gitclone the code

Comment: or can add ssh key to travis